# How to create Polygon out of {'northeast': {'lat':}, 'southwest': {'lat': }} (google maps) Python

Tags: python, geometry, shapely, geopandas

Google Maps returns location bounds as a square with 'northeast' and 'southwest' points.

How to calculate a Polygon out of this data?

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a dictionary like this:

```
bounds = {'northeast': {'lat': 10, 'lng': 15}, 'southwest': {'lat': 5, 'lng': 6}}
```

then you can use the `shapely.geometry.box` function, which takes "minx, miny, maxx, maxy" as arguments:

```
from shapely.geometry import box

bounds_polygon = box(bounds['southwest']['lng'], bounds['southwest']['lat'],
                     bounds['northeast']['lng'], bounds['northeast']['lat'])
```

which gives:

```
>>> print(bounds_polygon)
POLYGON ((15 5, 15 10, 6 10, 6 5, 15 5))
```