# Convert geometry from bounds to Polygon

Tags: python, geospatial, polygon, geopandas

I have a geopandas DataFrame with bounds geometry.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
                        'id': [0, 1],
                        'b': [((40.6494140625, -86.7919921875), (40.69335937...)), 
                              ((39.55078125, -93.8232421875), (39.5947265625...))]
                      })

gdf['b'][0]

Bounds(sw=SouthWest(lat=32.8271484375, lon=-96.8115234375), ne=NorthEast(lat=32.87109375, lon=-96.767578125))

print(type(gdf['b'][0]))

<class 'geolib.geohash.Bounds'>
```

How do I turn `Bounds` into `Polygon` geometry type? Like,

```
Polygon((40.6494140625, -86.7919921875), (40.69335937...))
```

Comment: dunno what the bounds object / class is.  anyway it's simple https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094357/how-to-create-polygon-out-of-northeast-lat-southwest-lat-go

Comment: Use shapely box(minx,miny,maxx,maxy) which returns a Polygon

Comment: @RobRaymond Yep, I tried this. However, why does the polygon look so short? i.e there are only 5 points. Given the area size, shouldn't it be much longer with several more points comprising the polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have:-

```
# bound1 = The geohash.Bounds object.
```

you can proceed with:-

```
from shapely.geometry import box
bounds_pgon = box(bounds1.sw.lon, bounds1.sw.lat,
                  bounds1.ne.lon, bounds1.ne.lat)
# Check the result
bounds_pgon.wkt
```

the output will be similar to this:-

```
'POLYGON ((-27.9986 70.2987, -27.9986 70.3001, -28.0000 70.3001, -28.0000 70.2987, -27.9986 70.2987))'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really the same answer that @swatchi has provided.

Shape of the geometry is defined by the precision of the hash.  See reference: [geohash](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html)

```
import geolib.geohash
import shapely.geometry
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

# Bounds(sw=SouthWest(lat=32.8271484375, lon=-96.8115234375), ne=NorthEast(lat=32.87109375, lon=-96.767578125))
# regenerate the referenced geohad bounds
b = geolib.geohash.bounds(
    geolib.geohash.encode(lat=32.8271484375, lon=-96.8115234375, precision=5)
)

print(b)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    pd.DataFrame({"id": [0], "b": [b]}).assign(
        geometry=lambda d: d["b"].apply(
            lambda b: shapely.geometry.box(b.sw.lon, b.sw.lat, b.ne.lon, b.ne.lat)
        )
    ),
    crs="epsg:4326",
)

gdf.explore(height=300, width=300)
```

#### output

```
Bounds(sw=SouthWest(lat=32.8271484375, lon=-96.8115234375), ne=NorthEast(lat=32.87109375, lon=-96.767578125))
```

[image]

Comment: I think the `geopandas` `centroid` method is causing issues. when I apply `.centroid` on polygon `POLYGON ((-96.8115234375 32.87109375, -96.8115234375 -96.767578125, 32.8271484375 -96.767578125, 32.8271484375 32.87109375, -96.8115234375 32.87109375))`, I get `POINT (-31.9921875 -31.9482421875)` which is not accurate.

Comment: you question clearly states you want geometry, a polygon is geometry.   are you changing your question?  you want a point to represent a Geohash?  I remember from months ago you regularly change your question after receiving an answer that fully covers the question ....

Comment: I am not changing the question. I suppose it is outside the scope of this question and is more of a follow up question, so here you go - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73595549/calculate-the-centroid-of-a-rectangle-geometry-in-python