# Calculate the centroid of a rectangle geometry in python

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas

I have the following Polygon geometry. When I calculate the `centroid`, I get an invalid / inaccurate `POINT`. I am using `geopandas` `centroid` to calculate the point.

https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.centroid.html

```
import shapely
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.geometry import box
import geopandas as gpd

g = "POLYGON ((-96.8115234375 32.87109375, -96.8115234375 -96.767578125, 32.8271484375 -96.767578125, 32.8271484375 32.87109375, -96.8115234375 32.87109375))"

print(wkt.loads(g).centroid)

POINT (-31.9921875 -31.9482421875)
```

How do I calculate the centroid POINT `lat`, `long` coordinates of the box? The shape of the Polygon is rectangle.

Comment: Why is that centroid wrong? What should it be?

Comment: @MattDMo the polygon represents a rectangle area in Dallas, TX. The centroid doesn't. If you try to plot in one the map, it's a point in South Atlantic Ocean.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine, your polygon is not and does not represents a rectangle area in Dallas, TX. Let's split it into vertices to make it apparent:

```
g = "POLYGON ((-96.8115234375 32.87109375, 
               -96.8115234375 -96.767578125, 
               32.8271484375  -96.767578125,
               32.8271484375  32.87109375,
               -96.8115234375 32.87109375))"
```

The first point is good and is indeed in Dallas. The second point has wrong latitude, -96.7... (it is south of South pole :) - however Shapely does not care and accepts it). Third point has wrong both latitude and longitude, etc. Apparently, latitudes and longitudes got mixed up here.

Comment: that makes sense; here's a related question for more context. I am converting the `bounds` to `polygon`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73588809/convert-geometry-from-bounds-to-polygon/73594710?noredirect=1#comment129962133_73594710